# Hosting ASP.NET Core 5 Web API on IIS: an error occurred while starting the application

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, hosting, .net-5

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project that I'm trying to host on IIS. Everything worked fine:

- I installed the .NET Core hosting bundle
- I added `IIS_IUSRS` to allow the access to the published application folder

When I open the published application in cmd and run `dotnet myAppName.dll`, everything is working fine and I can test all my apis and all of them are working well.

But when I browse my project from IIS, I get this error:

> An error occurred while starting the application

This is my startup.cs:

```
namespace storedProcedure
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            //adding dbContext service
            services.AddDbContext<trainingContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString
            ("trainingDB"))) ;

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "storedProcedure", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDirectoryBrowser();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "storedProcedure v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\paul\web2-Net-CORE\storedProcedure\storedProcedure\Resources"),
                RequestPath = "/Resources"
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(
              options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
            ); 

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Program.cs`:

```
namespace storedProcedure
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
 
                });
    }
}
```

NOTE: I'm integrating SQL Server database with my project and I added the database publish settings:

[Click here to see an image of my db publish settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwwSO.png)

Comment: The better is you show the error page so that other can know what kind of error it is. `An error occurred while starting the application` It just a reminder without useful information. So you need to check error page and event viewer to get detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BruceZhang and sorry if my question is dump but where can I find the error page or event viewer, I' new to .Net

Comment: if i inspect the browser page this error is appearing in console:      Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  :8082/favicon.ico:1 , It appears that the server couldn't find favicon.ico:1 but i didn't inculded such icon in my proj

Comment: @BruceZhang I checked my iis logs in event viewer and this is the exeption: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\paul\web2-Net-CORE\storedProcedure\storedProcedure\Resources\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)........  ANY SUGGSESTIONS? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, The Resources folder (where my static files are), was not included in the published folder, that's why it was giving me an error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).